# Is it necessary to keep data.fs.old after packing?

Tags: plone, zope, zodb

My data.fs was 500 MB, so I packed it then backed it up, resulting in 100 MB.

My hosting account is only 500 MB, so I am wondering if it is safe to delete data.fs.old (500 MB)?

Comment: This is off-topic. But it is safe to delete it (if your backup system is supposed to work).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to keep it and you can let the pack process remove it for you. To remove it automatically specify the `pack-keep-old` option in the zeoserver section:

```
[zeo]
recipe = plone.recipe.zeoserver
...
pack-keep-old = false
pack-days = 2
```

The pack process will still create a new file during packing, so you do need to have enough free disk space to hold both your Data.fs and a copy of it.

Via the `pack-days` option you can specify how many days of history you want to preserve. If you trust your system backup, you can set this to a low value, which will save some more disk space.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can safely delete it; it's a backup of the database from before the pack.

If the pack went haywire for some reason, you could use it to restore the database to the state it was before packing, by simply moving it back to `Data.fs`.